# Cucumber testing is not working for dropdown list with I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, integration-testing

This is my code in view file:

```
<%= f.label t('city'), class: "form-control-label" %><i>(<%= t('select-a-city', :default => 'Select a city') %>)</i>
<%= f.select :city, options_for_select(['city1', 'city2', 'city3']), {}, class: "form-control" %>
```

This is cucumber step definition:

```
Then(/^I select "([^"]*)" from the "([^"]*)" dropdown list$/) do |param1, city| 
  select(param1, :from => I18n.t(city))
end
```

This throws this error: 
**Unable to find select box "City" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/support/step_definitions/home_page_steps.rb:27:in `/^I select "city1" from the "City" dropdown list$/'**

But if I modify the view file like this:

```
<%= f.label :city, class: "form-control-label" %><i>(<%= t('select-a-city', :default => 'Select a city') %>)</i>
```

the test passes successfully.

So, my first clue was, may be cucumber can't retrieve the translation. I searched a lot, tried some suggestions like using :locale from the ENV etc. 
But nothing works.

**NB:** searching content works with or without the translation (I18n).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Trying throwing `binding.pry` or `byebug` into your ERB template. `<%- binding.pry %>`, for example. Then reload the page and you can play around with the variables in that context in the console (the one running your server).

Comment: Cucumber is the test framework. It does not interact with dropdowns. You are probably using some other library for that. Maybe capybara or selenium.

Comment: Yes, I am using capybara with selenium as web driver. I made the test passed with wrapping up the select option in id attribute. But this is like happy path. I didn't try poltergeist web driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use element selector and option value as selected dropdown options. The option will be selected depending on the value.

Example:

```
# When I select option "My Test Inc Account" from ".accounts-dropdown"
When(/^I select option "(.*?)" from element "(.*?)"$/) do |option, 
selector|
  all(selector).last.find(:option, option).select_option
end
```

You can read more in [this article](https://kolosek.com/cucumber-cheat-sheet/), it explains different types of steps you can write in cucumber.